# Calculate 15 minutes ago in shell

Tags: bash, shell, date

I have a time-stamp like 7:00:00, which means 7am.

I would like to write a short command that returns 06:45:00, or simply 06:45, preferably using date command so that I can avoid long shell script. Do you have any elegant solution?

I'm also looking for a 24h format. For example, 12:00:00 - 15 minutes = 11:45:00.

Comment: How do you want to handle Daylight Saving Time? For example: if the timestamp is `02:05:00`, then is `02:50` ever a valid result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With GNU `date`,  use `7:00:00 AM - 15 minutes` as `d` (`--date`) string :

```
% date -d '7:00:00 AM - 15 minutes' '+%H:%M'
06:45
```

`+%H:%M` sets the output format as `HH:MM`.

Comment: @kensaii `%H` shows 24 hour formatted hour, test with `date -d '7:00:00 PM - 15 minutes' '+%H:%M'`

Comment: thanks. Actually I know that but what I mean was the input is 24 hour formatted. Like 18:00:00 instead of 6:00:00 pm. Your code runs fine for PM but I just can't run with afternoon hours. Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 1):

On BSD variants Date has a -v flag which can be used to take the current timestamp and display the result of a positive or negative adjustment.

This will subtract 15mins from the current timestamp:

`date -v -15M`